# How to unhide an application window started by Jenkins "windows command"?

Tags: jenkins

I have defined a third party application to run as part of job finalizing process in a "windows batch command":

```
"C:\Program Files\Folder\App.exe"
```

Jenkins runs this and it works fine. but sometimes the    App.exe    is waiting for user action cause something went wrong, but since the application window is hidden I dont know what went wrong.

Is there a way to ask Jenkins to not hide the application window started by the windows batch command?

The jenkins is running as a windows service and using the same account as the logged in user on the jenkins box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope and it isn't Jenkins fault. [In Windows NT operating systems, a Windows service is a computer program that **operates in the background**.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_service)

In former Windows version there was a option `"Allow service to interact with desktop"` but since [Vista the setting **no longer works**.](http://asprosys.blogspot.de/2009/03/allow-service-to-interact-with-desktop.html)

Comment: thanks, that was all I needed "allow this service to interact with desktop"; at least I can see whats going on now